# Simple regex with repeated unordered matches

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

I have this regex

```
/^[a-z]{1,}( (?=[a-z])){0,}(_(?=[a-z])){0,}[a-z]{0,}$/
```

I want to match

```
ag_b_cf_ajk
```

or

```
zva b c de
```

or

```
hh_b opxop a_b
```

so any character tokens separated by a single space or underscore.

(In the regex above, we have a literal space, which is legal, and we have look-aheads that ensure that a space or underscore is followed by a character).

The problem is, my above regex is only matching the first space or underscore, like so:

```
axz_be
axz be
```

but these fail

```
axz_be_j
axz be j
```

I believe I missing some concept with regexes in order to solve this as I have been trying for the last few hours!

Comment: What about `^([a-z][ _]?)+$`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems you can just use

```
^[a-z]+(?:[_ ][a-z]+)*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dG0wC9/1)

The regex matches

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-z]+` - one or more lowercase ASCII letters
- `(?:[_ ][a-z]+)*` - zero or more sequences of:

  - `[_ ]`  -  a space or an underscore
  - `[a-z]+` - one or more lowercase ASCII letters
- `$` - end of string

If the space or underscore must appear at least once, use the `+` quantifier instead of `*`:

```
^[a-z]+(?:[_ ][a-z]+)+$
                     ^
```

To add a multicharacter alternative to the underscore and hyphen, you need to introduce another non-capturing group:

```
^[a-z]+(?:(?:[_ ]|\[])[a-z]+)+$
```

See [another regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dG0wC9/2)

Comment: The `(?:...)` is a non-capturing group that is only used to group some subpatterns but does not store the captured texts inside any memory buffer.

Comment: thanks, what if I wanted to include [] along with a space and underscore? The problem I have is [] is two characters instead of one, and I don't know how to put two characters in the "or" statement, where the space and underscore are side by side

Comment: I added that example at the bottom of the answer.

Comment: thanks! I think you forgot an escape char "\[]" becomes "\[\]" right?

Comment: I have not forgotten, if it is for JS, you do not need to escape `]` that is not a part of the character class.

Comment: could you explain in one more sentence how the nested non-capturing groups work?

Comment: The `(?:(?:[_ ]|\[])[a-z]+)+` is still a 1+ sequences of `(?:[_ ]|\[])[a-z]+`: either a `_`, a space or a `[]` sequence followed with 1+ letters.